# Elasticsearch array query scoring

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I have two items in my index:

Item 1:

```
labels:dog, olde english bulldogge, mammal, vertebrate, dog breed, old english bulldog, dog like mammal, bulldog, american bulldog, toy bulldog  _id:AVq7hHqnISG9gYnzrjSj _type:product _index:products _score:1
```

Item 2:

```
labels:dog, olde english bulldogge, mammal, vertebrate, dog breed, old english bulldog, dog like mammal, bulldog, american bulldog, toy bulldog  _id:AVq7hHmKISG9gYnzrjSi _type:product _index:products _score:1
```

The labels are pretty much the same. When I do the following query:
URL

```
https://blablabla/products/product/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
```

Body

```
"query" : {
  "terms" : {
    {
      "labels" : [
        "dog",
        "olde english bulldogge",
        "mammal",
        "vertebrate",
        "dog breed",
        "old english bulldog",
        "dog like mammal",
        "bulldog",
        "american bulldog",
        "toy bulldog"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get both the items back but the scores are surprisingly low (0.1499). Shouldn't they be the highest possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I actually had 14 of the same items (as shown in the question) out of maybe 40. The relevance of the results is low even though they're a perfect match because of how ES does its scoring. Since there were so many exact hits, it was deemed that the chances of the individual result being what I was looking for was low; as opposed to if my search had one exact hit and many other near hits.